# Prevent checkbox uncheck event when datagrid is in invalid state

Tags: wpf, silverlight, events, data-binding, datagrid

In Silverlight (but will probably equally apply to wpf) I have a datagrid which has validation and can go into an invalid state. I check this by:

```
if(grid.IsValid)
{
    ...
}
```

I have a checkbox that triggers saving when unchecked, I wish for this checkbox to be disabled, or at least not uncheck if the grid is in an invalid state.

Something like:

```
BeforeUncheckEvent
{
    if(datagridisvalid)
        allow;
    else
        disallow;
}
```

Binding to the `IsEnabled` based on the grids `IsValid` would be even better. This does not work:

```
IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=grid, Path=IsValid, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

UPDATE>>

I have tried binding another checkbox to the grids IsValid and that works, even when the other checkbox is almost identical to the one that does not work.

SOME CODE>>

When I check this :

```
    <CheckBox x:Name="chkAllowManual" Checked="chkAllowManual_Checked" Unchecked="chkAllowManual_Unchecked" Content="Allow Manual" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="3,0,7,0" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=grdPrices, Path=IsValid}">
    </CheckBox>
```

The grid gets its itemsource set, has some errors after edit then this gets disabled properly (not the original checkbox but the one next to it) :

```
    <CheckBox x:Name="chkAllowManual1" Checked="chkAllowManual_Checked" Unchecked="chkAllowManual_Unchecked" Content="Allow Manual1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="3,0,7,0" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=grdPrices, Path=IsValid}">
    </CheckBox>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: where is IsValid defined? in Viewmodel or Code behind?

Comment: @nit its part of the datagrid in silverlight

Comment: bro will need to see your code xaml and codebehind to crack this.. ideally it should work

Comment: What error did you get when you tried the `IsEnabled` binding that you say didn't work? (You can find errors in the Output Window in Visual Studio.)

Comment: @Sheridan no error. I am beginning to think the binding gets removed as a converter attached to it does not even get called when the IsInvalid=true ... all I do after the initial binding and it not working is reset the itemsource of the grid, maybe that is doing it somehow...

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to a reference of your `DataGrid` wherever the `Checked` handler is, then you could try doing this:

```
private void chkAllowManual_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!dataGrid.IsValid) e.Handled = true;
    else
    {
        // do your stuff here
    }
}
```

This should stop it from becoming checked when `dataGrid.IsValid` is flase.

Comment: Unfortunately e.Handled/e.Cancel does not exist, if it did I would not have this issue.